# Read custom property from function.json file in Azure Function Trigger

Tags: azure-functions

How can we read some custom properties in the function.json file for an Azure Function?

I want to read the value of a property that I just added to the function.json file in our run.csx file.

And I am doing this on the Azure portal itself.

**Note: I could not find a solution anywhere on the internet.**

Comment: You should not read data from the function.json file. It is designed to provide the function definition. If you need to access custom data, you can store these dat as app settings.

Comment: @Thomas Okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure function has a specific schema , you cannot or not supposed to add custom configuration there. http://json.schemastore.org/function

You should be using Azure functions App'settings for that as described in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. `ExecutionContext.FunctionDirectory` will provide the path to the function's local directory that contains its `function.json` file. Then it is a simple matter of access that file as normal from within your function. In the example below I am using `ConfigurationBuilder` to load the file like any other JSON config file.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(context.FunctionDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("function.json")
            .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true)
            .Build();

        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        log.LogInformation($"Fucntion Setting value: {config["generatedBy"}");
}
```

I am offering no comment on the wisdom of having custom values in `function.json`.

During development, Visual Studio creates, and rec-creates, `function.json` often so it could be tricky to inject values into `function.json`. (I needed to manually edit the `function.json` files within the bin folder after building the project but before running the project.)

The values within `function.json` aren't available to be used as parameters for any trigger/input/output binds. So you are can't do the following:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%customproperty%")] TimerInfo myTimer, ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
```